# Remove 'empty row' (as first row) and 'Index' at column level

Tags: python, pandas

I wanted to delete first column which contain "B" at level=1 and drop first row which is empty (as you can see in first image output file generated after using above code:- in that row is empty which need to delete and index column also need to be deleted).

I have tried this code :-

```
table = df1.groupby(['Remark3','Remark2','Date_','Band'], sort=False)[value].sum().unstack('Band').reset_index()
```

and getting this output after trying above code :-

[image: output-1]

but i required this as an output :-

[image: output-2 as a desired output]

Answer (score 0):

if every time first row is empty then you can just hardcode it and get rid of the first row by `df.iloc[1:]`

and you can print the df without index by `df.to_string(index=False)`

Comment: thanks but none of these working.......... your row code is not changing anything its given same output-1, while for index i'm using excel Writer because need to save 3 excel sheets so given error